# Adding a newborn child to US tourist visa (B1/B2)

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, children

My wife and I have a 3 year B1/B2 US visa and we got it before having a child. Now since we have our newborn child, we'd like to travel to US again. So somehow we need to add our child to our visas. 
Do we need to apply for a dedicated application for a child?
Do we need to go in person with a child to embassy for this? Somewhere it was mentioned for applicants <14 there is no need to be in person for this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need a new application for your child, you cannot **add** your child to an already approved visa.

It makes sense to carry the child along to the interview although they indicate it is not mandatory. In theory you do not have to take the child along, however in practice it’s sometimes different and they will ask for the child.

In theory you don’t have to carry a bank statement or indeed any documents (except those listed below) along for a USA B visa interview. In practice very very very few people get approved without some documents.

You are the legal guardians of the child I assume and you will have to prove you are actually his parents via a birth certificate or other means.

[Required Documentation](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) per Department of State

> Gather and prepare the following required documents before your visa
>   interview:
>
> Passport valid for travel to the United States – Your passport must be
>   valid for at least six months beyond your period of stay in the United
>   States (unless exempt by country-specific agreements). Each individual
>   who needs a visa must submit a separate application, including any
>   family members listed in your passport.
>
> Nonimmigrant Visa Application, Form DS-160 confirmation page.
>
> Application fee payment receipt, if you are required to pay before
>   your interview.
>
> Photo – You will upload your photo while completing the online Form
>   DS-160. If the photo upload fails, you must bring one printed photo in
>   the format explained in the Photograph Requirements.

Comment: Perfect, fully answered my requests.

Comment: We say thanks you here by voting the answer (using the vote tab) and then clicking on accept for that best answer (using the accept tab).

Comment: "It makes sense to go to the interview with the child although they indicate it is not mandatory." I interpreted this as "your newborn is permitted to attend the interview alone but it might make sense to accompany them" and was briefly fascinated by this kid's precociousness.

Comment: In some usa embassies the child must attend the interview.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to enter the US, all children, including infants, needs his/her own valid travel document/passport and visa. Citizens of countries eligible for the Visa Waiver Program would apply for the ESTA. As you did for your visa, you would need to [file a DS-160](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application.html) and pay the applicable fee.

Generally, children under 14 do not need to appear for an interview. The website of the US Consulate that serves your country or area should have the specifics.